# Can I show more than just the 24p icon on status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, icons, status

Is it true that an app can only produce a 24p icon on the status bar and not wider?

Or is there a workaround? I would love to show in the status bar either:

- An icon wider than 24p (so that I can fit in text like "1h29m left!")
- Text, e.g. "You have 1h29m left!"

It'll be a deadlining app. 
It refreshes the remaining time every minute - it would be great if the remaining time could be displayed straight away on the status bar so that the user can view it at all times - without the need to swipe down to see the notification bar every time.
24p is too narrow.

Thanks a lot!